Changing geometry column data type in all tables of a schema
I have a database of almost 500 tables. For most of them, the type is set to 'GEOMETRY'. I need to switch the type to be POINT, LINE or POLYGON.
Using this query :
select f_table_name, f_geometry_column, type
from geometry_columns
where f_table_schema = 'my_schema'

I get the list of all the tables in my schema with the current data type.
Using this :
select split_part(ST_AsText(geom), '(', 1) from my_schema.example_table group by split_part(ST_AsText(geom), '(', 1)

I can find the actual type of the data in each table (there are never multiple types in a table).
How can I loop on this information to change the data type of all tables in the schema to the actual object type inside it ?

You want do execute a DO block with dynamic SQL injection. From the top of my head:
DO
$DO$
  DECLARE
    target_table record;
      
    geometry_type TEXT;
    geometry_srid TEXT;

  BEGIN
    FOR target_table IN (
      SELECT
        f_table_name,
        f_table_schema,
        f_geometry_column
      FROM
        public.geometry_columns
      WHERE
        f_table_schema = '<your_schema>'
    ) LOOP
      RAISE NOTICE 'Fetching geometry type and SRID for table %.%...', target_table.f_table_schema, target_table.f_table_name;
      EXECUTE FORMAT(
        $FORMAT$
          SELECT
            GeometryType(%3$I),
            ST_SRID(%3$I)
          FROM
            %1$I.%2$I
          LIMIT
            1
          ;
        $FORMAT$,
        target_table.f_table_schema, target_table.f_table_name, target_table.f_geometry_column
      ) INTO
        geometry_type, geometry_srid
      ;

      RAISE NOTICE 'Updating table %.% [Geometry type: % | SRID: %]...', target_table.f_table_schema, target_table.f_table_name, geometry_type, geometry_srid;
      EXECUTE FORMAT(
        $FORMAT$
          ALTER TABLE %1$I.%2$I
            ALTER COLUMN %3$I TYPE GEOMETRY(%4$s, %5$s)
              USING %3$I::GEOMETRY(%4$s, %5$s)
          ;
        $FORMAT$,
        target_table.f_table_schema, target_table.f_table_name, target_table.f_geometry_column, geometry_type, geometry_srid
      );

      --COMMIT;
    END LOOP;
  END;
$DO$
;

Note that I included a similar check for the SRID - if possible you want that set on the column level, too - so make sure that is desired, or remove all relevant parts.
Run the target_table selection query separately to validate the list of tables to get updated. Test this with a single table first (add a LIMIT 1 to the target_table query), then uncomment the COMMIT; to greatly reduce transactional overhead.
